# Aborted errors in Firebug when loading a Drupal 7 page via https

Tags: drupal, firefox, google-chrome, firebug, http-status-codes

Everyone in our web development unit get Firebug "Aborted" errors on random css, js and image objects when we load one of our Drupal 7 sites in https (and a force-refresh).  We don't know when the problem started.  Site was created about 2 years ago, and about 6 mo. ago we started getting CSS / JS / Image objects not loading when we force-refresh the page cache or clear the Drupal js / css file aggregation.

Researching online suggests that there is an AJAX interference problem, but I haven't seen that in our case.

No errors if:

- Page requested via HTTP / Port 80
- Objects already in cache
- Viewing the site in Prod (has a signed cert)

Errors even if:

- Upgrading Firefox and Firebug
- Turning off js / css aggregation
- Using Google Chrome

The server logs indicate no request for those files at all, so it's like the browser never sends the request.

The cert is self-signed.

[image: Screenshot of the Firebug Net panel]

Comment: You may try your luck with Fiddler, maybe it will reveal something (remember to [turn HTTPS decryption on](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)) -- whether there's some request sent at all or not. Might be also something with the server issue... But I'm just guessing.

Comment: did u get this solved ? if not please share the link to the site and I can try and help

Comment: The problem has gone away since we have since moved on to a new environment.  The new environment is very different, being load balanced and the https is offloaded to the load balancer.  The cert is signed.  Fiddler showed that the browser never made any kind of request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain request from HTTP to HTTPS aborts immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690191/cross-domain-request-from-http-to-https-aborts-immediately)

Comment: Thanks Paul.  In our case we are not making cross domain requests, but this issue may have the same root cause as that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Must be some certificate problem. Maybe it's revoked, expired or something.

Comment: Can that explain the random way that some files get Aborted by the server?  It's different files each time, and a different number of them.