# Cross domain request from HTTP to HTTPS aborts immediately

Tags: javascript, https, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to make Cross-Domain webservice calls from an HTTP page to an HTTPS service.

I have set up the proper CORS headers on the server (it works with HTTP-HTTP and HTTPS-HTTPS).

It *does* work if I change the requests to JSONp.

What I'm seeing in Chrome and Firefox is the HTTPS request is *never sent*, it's immediately *aborted*, and the server never sees the request.

It is worth noting that the preflight `OPTIONS` request is aborted (and it doesn't reach the server).

I can't find any source that explains that this is indeed not possible (HTTP to HTTPS) and better yet: explains *why*. I can understand HTTPS to HTTP is unsafe, but the othe way around should be fine right? It seems silly to me because JSONp works (but it's messy).

**notes**

I also have `withCredentials` set to `true` and I'm sending some custom headers and a custom `Content-Type`: `application/json`

I'm using the regular XMLHTTPRequest with fallbacks to JSONp for IE<=9

Comment: Do you have a live website where I can investigate ?

Comment: No I don't, I'm running it on a local development server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The certificate I'm using for the HTTPS domain is self-signed and unverified. Adding it to the list of trusted third-party authorities fixed it for me.

You can install the certificate in Windows 7 through IE. This worked for me:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bds-Ao9LigA%5B1-25%5D
post by `zacharysyoung 2/11/09`
Make sure you run IE(9) **as administrator** or the install will fail even-though it says it installed it correctly.

> 1. Open Internet Explorer (IE) and navigate to the site hosting the self-signed certificate.
> 2. IE should display a page warning that, 'There is a problem with this web site's security certificate.'
> 3. Click the, 'Continue to this website (not recommended)' link.
> 4. Once the page has loaded, look to the right of the address bar. A red/pink button, labeled 'Certificate Error,' should be visible. Click
>      that button.
> 5. A pop-up, titled 'Untrusted Certificate,'  will appear. Click the 'View certificates' link at the bottom of the pop-up.
> 6. Another pop-up, titled 'Certificate,' will appear. Click the 'Install Certificate...' button.
> 7. The 'Certificate Import Wizard' will be started. Click the 'Next' button.
> 8. ** For XP:    a. Leave 'Automatically select the certificate...' option selected, and click the 'Next' button.     ** For Vista:    a.
>      Choose 'Place all certificates in the following store' option, and
>      click the 'Browse' button.    b. Click the 'Show physica stores'
>      checkbox.    c. Expand the 'Third-Party Root Certification
>      Authorities' folder, and choose 'Local Computer'. Click the 'OK'
>      button.    d. Click the 'Next' button.
> 9. This should display the 'Completing the Certificate Import Wizard' dialog. Click the 'Finish' button.
> 10. A 'Security Warning' pop-up will appear. The warning is informing you that the certificate's origin cannot actually be validated. You
>       should know where the certificate is coming from. If you do, click the
>       'Yes' button to install the certificate.
> 11. A final pop-up informing you that, 'The import was successful,' will be displayed. Click the 'OK' button.
> 12. Restart/Open Chrome and navigate to the site in question. You should *not* be greeted by the security warning page.

Aside from that, I think I may have discovered a bug in Chrome. See:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141839

Comment: Super helpful. For others looking, Firefox will silently abort the OPTIONS request if the ssl cert has problems. I just fixed it by going directly to the domain and adding an exception for my local self-signed.  After that the OPTIONS requests worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to setup something like [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/).  It is rather quick to get going and will do all the backwards compatibility for you (all the way to IE6).  It might not be the home-grown solution you are looking for but if you want cross-domain (where you have access to both sides) in a hurry it fits the bill.

You could always write your own iframe (postMessage) interface but why re-invent the wheel (and don't forget to set your document.domain if you are using different sub-domains).

Comment: I have an implementation that works (JSONp). But I want to know _why_ Chrome and Firefox and blocking HTTP to HTTPS requests. easyXDM looks unmaintained, untidy, completely feature bloated and it requires .. Flash? An iframe fallback might be interesting if I want to do uploads or really large requests, but for now, I have no such requirements. I am also not 'in a hurry'.

Comment: For individual browsers the protocols have very large implications around privacy and security.  New browsers do have "Content-Security-Policy" but not sure if it is cross protocol.  I Might have jumped the gun in offering a solution but the [community for easyXDM](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/easyxdm) is still out there.  I believe the last change was less then a month ago (it is just pretty stable and does not need any new features).  As for as flash, it is used as a fallback when postMessage is not an option but it does have a large (overkill) feature-set.

Comment: I am not sure what your market really is but you might also be able to try [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and/or "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".  Again those are really directed toward cross-domain and not cross-protocol (but might be able to sneak by with one).

Comment: I am using CORS .. I thought I mentioned that? What is cross-protocol?

Comment: Looks like I am oblivious to the world around me sometime (working too many hours I guess).  HTTP & HTTPS are different protocols is what I meant by cross-protocol.  Anyway [W3C CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-security) mentions the user-agent can be considered independent of the page policy; and in turn will probably prevent https to http calls.

Comment: HTTPS to HTTP sure, I can understand that, but HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: I understand what you are saying (and I do have a few choice words for the w3c group in general), but http->https breaks the fundamental decision that [different protocol === different site/domains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  It is not going change, but you could write your own postMessage stuff like I suggested in the response (and I came across a [postMessage](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/) wrapper lib that will make it easier).