# HTTP site to HTTPS webservice using CORS

Tags: http, iis, https, ssl-certificate, cors

I have an HTML5/JS website on on domain, which uses an asp.mvc web service for CORS queries on another domain.

Everything works fine with HTTP -> HTTP however as we are now adding login and authentication mechanisms for user specific content we are wanting to enable HTTPS. However it just refuses to send the options request to the web service, just gives an "Aborted" status.

I am testing using Firefox and the web service is hosted on IIS7 with a self cert (generated with SelfSSL7).

Is there any known issues around this? I did check:

[Cross domain request from HTTP to HTTPS aborts immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690191/cross-domain-request-from-http-to-https-aborts-immediately)

However it mentions the solution is to make sure the cert is trusted, and to my knowledge SelfSSL is doing this using the /T option when I call it. So is there anything else which needs to be changed to get this working?

Comment: Got it working, I had to manually get Firefox to ignore the security issue, so it appears that it was not being flagged as trusted.

Comment: I just had the same issue, adding a security exception for the certificate fixed it.

Comment: It'd be helpful if firefox generated a more helpful error in the js console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will unfortunately need to manually set this in firefox, although I believe you can override this behaviour if you manually set the profile configuration.